# Looking to find a lower bound to this term

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I have this term I'm trying to bound(below). From numerical experimentation I'm fairly confident that the bound is 1/2. I've been out of school for a couple years and my proof skills have diminished considerably. Was wondering if anyone had any ideas how to approach this

$$\frac{\max((1)(n), (2)(n-1), (3)(n-2) ....(n)(1))} {\sum(1+2+3...+N))}$$

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, answer is pretty simple. You get

$$\max((1)(n), (2)(n-1), (3)(n-2) ....(n)(1)) \geq \frac{n(n+1)}{4}$$

by looking at the middle terms. Which directly proves the statement.